# Dynamic object works on one PC but not the other

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic

I've build a program that uses the Dynamic keyword.

at a point in my code I do this:

```
public void OnNext(ExpandoObject value)
{
    dynamic expando = value;
    if (expando.Attention == NotifyEnums.ALERT)
    {
        _needsAttention = true;
    }
}
```

And this works, so I submit it to SourceControl. Then my boss gets the files, tries to run it but gets an error on line `if (expando.Attention == NotifyEnums.ALERT)`, apparently expando.Attention does not exist in the dynamic object:

[image]

This confused me greatly, because we both target the same .NET version: `.NET Framework 4 Platform Update 1 KB2478063` and I KNOW the value is set in the code.

So I set a breakpoint before the dynamic value is read, and open up the Immediate Window.

`expando.Attention // Gives an exception on boss computer, works on my computer`

But look at the following:

```
(((IDictionary<String, object>)expando).ContainsKey("Attention"))
true // Returns "True" on boss computer and on my computer, WTF!
```

So I try the following:

```
(NotifyEnums)(((IDictionary<String, Object>)expando)["Attention"])
ALERT // Returns alert on boss computer
```

So to summarize:

```
public void OnNext(ExpandoObject value)
{
    dynamic expando = value;
    if (expando.Attention == NotifyEnums.ALERT)
    // CRASHES on boss pc, works on my pc
    // Error says Attention does not exist.
    {
        _needsAttention = true;
    }
}
```

AND

```
public void OnNext(ExpandoObject value)
{
    dynamic expando = value;
    if ((NotifyEnums)(((IDictionary<String, Object>)expando)["Attention"]) == NotifyEnums.ALERT)
    // WORKS on BOSS PC (wtf?) and works on my pc.
    {
        _needsAttention = true;
    }
}
```

So what is going on, can anyone elaborate?

**Edit:**

But there is another thing as well, after the Program Crahses, I click Continue, get the error again, click continue again and then the program continues as if nothing happened. It reads the correct value out of the dynamic object.

Comment: What happens if you run it on your boss's PC *not* in the debugger?

Comment: @JonSkeet

I'll try after the weekend is over :P

Comment: @JonSkeet Debugger or no Debugger, doesn't matter. Boss still gets the error. I sent my binaries to my boss PC and they worked fine. So it's something in the binaries. Unchecking `CLR exceptions` under `Debug -> Exceptions` in VS2010 stops this exception on Boss PC. But checking CLR Exceptions does not cause this exception to happen on my pc.

Comment: If you run the boss's binary on your PC, do you get the same error? The debug options around Debug->Exceptions shouldn't make any difference to the binary...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have first chance exceptions turned on the boss machine. Look under Debug/Exceptions and uncheck everything in the Thrown column.
It is normal for the expando object to throw an exception when the class doesn't implement the member directly, it uses the exception to fire a secondary lookup and return the correct information.

Comment: My boss isn't here atm, so I'll try what you suggest a little bit. What you say makes sense, but if I check everything in the thrown column(on my pc) and run the program, I get no exceptions for reading the expando object. Any idea why?

Comment: No idea. There is an option in Options/Debugging/General called "Enable Just My Code". When set, another column shows up in Debug/Exceptions called "User-unhandled". Perhaps this column might affect whether or not you catch those exceptions.

Comment: @JoelLucsy is right. Goto exceptions dialog and click reset all.

Comment: Okay my boss finally had time for me. And yes, this was it, unchecking CLR exceptions in the thrown column stops prevents the exception. But checking the thrown column on my PC does not cause an Exception :S .